# Insert Trigger Cannot capture value from INSERTED

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TUI_CRS] ON [dbo].[C_Rates_Shadow] 
   FOR UPDATE, INSERT
   AS BEGIN

    if exists (select 1 from INSERTED) begin

     RAISERROR('Result', 16, 1) 

    end
```

I cannot get error while inserting record. But record get inserted.

Comment: pls share your table structure & insert statement

Answer (score 3):

Just because you produce an error message, that doesn't mean that the transaction will be automatically rolled back. There could be situations where you want to report an error condition **and** have a permanent effect on the database. So, if you want to prevent the insert activity and report an error, you have to do *both* of those things yourself.

So, for example, this script:

```
create table T (ID int not null)
go
create trigger T_T on T
after insert
as
    if exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        RAISERROR('I''m an error but so what?',16,1)
    end
go
insert into T(ID) values (1),(2)
go
select * from T
```

Produces:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure T_T, Line 6
I'm an error but so what?

ID
-----------
1
2
```

Whereas if we re-write the trigger:

```
delete from T
go
drop trigger T_T
go
create trigger T_T on T
after insert
as
    if exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        RAISERROR('I''m an error and we''re going to stop',16,1)
        rollback
    end
go
insert into T(ID) values (1),(2)
go
select * from T
```

We get:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure T_T, Line 6
I'm an error and we're going to stop
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
ID
-----------
```